# How exactly do I use Assetic's Twig extension?

Tags: php, twig, assetic, twig-extension

I'm (trying to) use Assetic with Twig and Slim (so, without Symfony).  I think I've figured out the basics of creating an `AssetCollection`, but I'm not really clear how to link this collection in my templates.

```
$fm = new FilterManager();

$factory = new AssetFactory('');
$factory->setDebug(true);
$factory->setFilterManager($fm);

$app->css = $factory->createAsset([
    'assets://css/bootstrap-3.3.1.css',
    'assets://css/bootstrap-custom.css',
    'assets://css/paper.css'
], [
    // Filters here
]);
```

If I do something like `echo $app->css->dump();`, it correctly prints out all my CSS.  Great, but how do I hook this into Twig?

The example given in the project README leaves me with more questions than I started with:

```
{% stylesheets '/path/to/sass/main.sass' filter='sass,?yui_css' output='css/all.css' %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

What the heck is `/path/to/sass/main.sass`?  I thought I was declaring my assets via `$factory->createAsset`.  The documentation goes on to say:

> When the extension is in debug mode, this same tag will render multiple link elements, one for each asset referenced by the `css/src/*.sass` glob...

I don't see anything about `css/src/*.sass` anywhere else in the README.  What are they talking about?

Finally, I see this at the bottom of the README:

```
<?php

use Assetic\AssetWriter;
use Assetic\Extension\Twig\TwigFormulaLoader;
use Assetic\Extension\Twig\TwigResource;
use Assetic\Factory\LazyAssetManager;

$am = new LazyAssetManager($factory);

// enable loading assets from twig templates
$am->setLoader('twig', new TwigFormulaLoader($twig));

// loop through all your templates
foreach ($templates as $template) {
    $resource = new TwigResource($twigLoader, $template);
    $am->addResource($resource, 'twig');
}

$writer = new AssetWriter('/path/to/web');
$writer->writeManagerAssets($am);
```

This seems to me like something I would run once in a build step ("looping through all my templates").  But, I thought Assetic also would support on-demand filtering (and caching) of assets.  I obviously don't want to loop through all my templates on every request.  Shouldn't the relevant calls to `writeManagerAssets` be automatically triggered by the Twig extension?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.